# PHP удаление объектов при отсутствии на них ссылки

Tags: php

Прошу просветить в вопросе удения объектов в пхп. Допустим есть такой код -

```
$root = null;

function foo() {
    global $root;
    $objectOne = new stdclass();
    $objectTwo = new stdclass();
    $objectThree = new stdclass(); 
    $objectOne->next = $objectTwo;
    $objectTwo->next = $objectThree;
    $root = $objectOne;
}

unset($root);
```

Удаляться ли все объекты из памяти? Не будет ли утечки? 
Будут ли существовать все три объекта до операции `unset`?

Comment: Пых скрипты умирают сразу после завершения. `unset` используется для того, чтобы в ходе работы скриптов не забивало память и освобождать ее для следующего скрипта.

Comment: @And некоотрые пхп скрипты не умирают очень долго. Да и не в этом был вопрос.

Comment: На англоязычном есть ответ (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584960/whats-better-at-freeing-memory-with-php-unset-or-var-null). Сборщик мусора начнёт работу по своему усмотрению.

Comment: Сборщик мусора можно запускать принудительно https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.gc-collect-cycles.php